# Having trouble with array conversion into list in HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have been trying to figure out why I am receiving an error that says

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

on line 20 of my HTML file and I can not figure it out I have ran my PHP code independently from the HTML file and the PHP code returns my Objects as expected. As soon as I try to call it in my HTML file to display it does not work here are both my files

PHP:

```
require 'practice.view.php';

 class Task {

  public $description;

  public $completed = false;

  public function __construct($description){

    $this->description = $description;
  }

  public function complete(){

    $this->completed = true;
  }

  public function iscomplete(){

    return $this->completed;
  }
}




$tasks = [
  new Task('Go to the market'),

  new Task('eat a marshmellow'),

  new Task('Join a soccer league')
];



die(var_dump($tasks));
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<!meta charset="utf-8"->

  <title>Practice</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Tasks List </h1>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) : ?>

          <li>
            <?= $task->description; ?>
          </li>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you on advance for any help

Comment: If `$tasks` doesn't exist, it's not going to work no. You need to include the php file in your html part or it simply doesn't know what `$tasks` is. Also `<?= $task->description; ?>`?? Try `<?php echo $task->description; ?>` instead.

Comment: @icecub  have called the html file into my php file where the 'Requires...' is so I do  not understand why or how I would call it the reverse way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was simply the placement of my "require..." statement it is at the top of my code in this case when it should be at the bottom of my code in the PHP file. Thanks for all that attempted to answer this question

```
 class Task {

  public $description;

  public $completed = false;

  public function __construct($description){

    $this->description = $description;
  }

  public function complete(){

    $this->completed = true;
  }

  public function iscomplete(){

    return $this->completed;
  }
}




$tasks = [
  new Task('Go to the market'),

  new Task('eat a marshmellow'),

  new Task('Join a soccer league')
];



die(var_dump($tasks));

require 'practice.view.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

filename.php,

```
<?php

  class Task {

  public $description;

  public $completed = false;

  public function __construct($description){

    $this->description = $description;
   }

  public function complete(){

    $this->completed = true;
  }

  public function iscomplete(){

    return $this->completed;
  }
}




$tasks = [
  new Task('Go to the market'),

  new Task('eat a marshmellow'),

  new Task('Join a soccer league')
];

?>
```

Html,

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<!meta charset="utf-8"->

  <title>Practice</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php require 'filename.php'; ?>

  <h1>Tasks List </h1>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) : ?>

          <li>
            <?= $task->description; ?>
          </li>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html
```

You should include your class in your html file using require 'filename.php'; you are doing it opposite you are including your html in the class file.

Comment: Don't use answers for what should be a comment pls. You're not solving the problem. You're giving advise on how to debug it.

Comment: I am sharing my experience in my answer.

Comment: I have already made sure that the object exists and functions properly in PHP the trouble lies in HTML your answer @ShoyebSheikh just reiterated what I have already explained

Comment: You should include your class in your html file using require 'filename.php'; you are doing it opposite you are including your html in the class file.

Comment: @icecub I apologize for misleading.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh I think you are mistaken again the PHP tags take care of the PHP implementation in the HTML file since it is instantiated in the PHP in the 'Requires...' section so that part is correct to my understanding